# ¿ Qué falla en este código para Google Map?

Tags: java, android

Estoy siguiendo lo siguiente, que es muy muy sencillo el código y muy breve :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=es-419

Pero yo lo tengo en un Fragment y estoy poniendo esto:

`public class FirstMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.five_tab, container, false);

  MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapid);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return  ;
    }

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}
```

}

Antes me daba un fallo pero ahora me compila bien pero no me funciona ni me carga el mapa, donde esta el fallo?

El .xml es :

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapid"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prueba.rudeboys.rudeboys1/com.prueba.rudeboys.rudeboys1.MainActivity1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at com.prueba.rudeboys.rudeboys1.First_fragment.onCreateView(First_fragment.java:26)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5336)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)_

**EDITADO**

`public class First_fragment extends Fragment {`

```
WebView appWeb;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab, container, false);
    String url = "https://rudeboysweb.wordpress.com/";
    appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
    appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //Cargamos el enlace definido
    appWeb.loadUrl(url);
    //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
    appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

**first_tab.XML**

```
<WebView
    android:name="@+id/mywebview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Estoy usando un móvil con jelly bean, tiene algo que ver o no? No... no?

Comment: Alguna ayuda?? Por cierto, he quitado todo del google map y sigue dando fallo , por lo que leo en los errores en es MainActiivty1, modifique alguna cosas del build y tal, sera por eso que se me detiene la aplicacion?

Comment: Esto ya lo habias preguntado no es así??? Cual es la linea 26 del First_Fragment.java

Comment: Esto es otro codigo, mas facil, para ver s iba, pero no va nada. linea 26 es  : appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error ocurre en la clase  `First_Fragment.java` linea 26 no al cargar el mapa!

Es esta linea:   `appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Verifica dentro de tu fragmento First_fragment que tu layout que se carga, contenga el WebView especificado con el id definido.

En este caso no se estaba especificando el id correctamente, únicamente se definia el nombre:

```
android:name="@+id/mywebview"
```

Debe ser:

```
android:id="@+id/mywebview"
```

Comment: vale, me espero, he reiniciado proyecto porque esto me sobrepasaba, pero sigo con el otro, porque hacer todo de nuevo es mucho trabajo.

Comment: En la otra pregunta puse el First_Fragment.java , lo pongo tambien aqui?

Comment: Elena ese codigo es para un webView y me ha funcionado tal como está. En mi codigo, que esta puesto en mi otra pregunta, dos lineas mas abajo ya hago: ``appWeb.setWebViewClient(...``

Comment: Edite la respuesta Verifica dentro de tu fragmento First_fragment que tu layout que se carga, contenga el WebView especificado

Comment: Eso ha dejado de funcionar desde que me he puesto con los indeseables API de Google.

Comment: Si no me va, voy a intentar cargar este proyecto que me guardé cuando si funcionaba y te comento el caso de las API de Google, porque tengo algunas dudas

Comment: Vale, ya esta arreglado el fallo Elena, no era android:name, era android:id ... tantas horas perdidas para nada.... Voy a ponerme con Google API y tengo unas dudas , las comento por aqui o abro una pregunta nueva? O abre chat si puedes y quieres ;)

Comment: Por esa razón no encontraba el elemento.

Comment: Entonces era lo que habia comentado en la comentado verificar si se encuentra el elemento. Edite respuesta.

Comment: Claro, por eso cuando accedia al webView daba fallo en esa linea.. en fin, gracias, si no, hubiera empezado otro, voy a abrir otra pregunta en un ratin sobre google mapi que vaya tela.